# How to display null value to UITableView? If tag not found in webservice Response in iphone sdk

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsxmlparser

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"PublicBusinessName"])
    {
    boolListofareasdata=YES;
    }
    else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"ProfessionName"])
    {
        boolListofareasdata1=YES;
    }
    else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"PublicContactEmail"])
    {
        boolListofareasdata2=YES;
    }
    else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"PublicBusinessURL"])
    {
        boolListofareasdata3=YES;
    }
    else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"BrandLogoName"])
    {
        boolListofareasdata4=YES;
    }
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (boolListofareasdata)
    {
        [arrareasdata addObject:string];

        NSLog(@"NAME...............%@",arrareasdata);
    }
    else if (boolListofareasdata1)
    {
        [arrareasdata1 addObject:string];

        NSLog(@"DESIGN..............%@",arrareasdata1);
    }
    else if (boolListofareasdata2)
    {
        [arrareasdata2 addObject:string];

        NSLog(@"DESIGN..............%@",arrareasdata1);
    }
    else if (boolListofareasdata3)
    {
        [arrareasdata3 addObject:string];

        NSLog(@"WEB....................%@",arrareasdata3);
    }
    else if (boolListofareasdata4)
    {
        [arrareasdata4 addObject:str];

        NSLog(@"WEB....................%@",arrareasdata4);
    }
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:   (NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PublicBusinessName"])
    {
        boolListofareasdata=NO; 
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"ProfessionName"])
    {
        boolListofareasdata1=NO; 
    }
    else if( [elementName isEqualToString:@"PublicContactEmail"])
    {
        boolListofareasdata2=NO;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"PublicBusinessURL"])
    {
        boolListofareasdata3=NO; 
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"BrandLogoName"])
    {
        boolListofareasdata4=NO; 
    }
}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{   
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arrareasdata3 count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {        
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

        for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
            {
                cell =  (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER........................");
    cell.nameLabel.text = [arrareasdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.designLabel.text = [arrareasdata1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.emailLabel.text = [arrareasdata2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.webLabel.text = [arrareasdata3 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear and you're code dump doesn't help much.  What element is missing?  What data is returned?  What does your custom cell do?  What's the output of your NSLog.  Work on narrowing down your question and code and someone may be able to help

Comment: Actually i'm fetching some value and display into tableview. In this case some empty tag comming from asmx response. so i can't able to check that empty tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add null value in uitableviewcell like this:

```
 NSString *strName = [arrareasdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 if((strName.length > 0)  
 {
   cell.nameLabel.text = strName;
 }
 else
 {
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"";
 }
 //same logic for designLabel,emailLabel,webLabel in which u will fill your data
```

Comment: Property 'length' not found on object of type 'id'     if(([arrareasdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].length > 0)  
 {
   cell.nameLabel.text = [arrareasdata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
 }
 else
 {
    cell.nameLabel.text = @"";
 }

Comment: In case group of value getting(like name,age,address) from webservices, if age tag not coming from sometimes remaining two tag getting... how to check this?....

Comment: your age tag array will be having count 0 check like this if([yourAgeArray count] > 0){ // age values are } else { //no age value }

Comment: my id is navadiya_paresh@rediffmail.com and what's problem in code

Comment: please send me on navadiya_paresh@yahoo.com as rediff cannot be opened in my company